# How to make content: '' (empty) or remove ::before selector in Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

My input has a ::before selector, I want to remove it with tailwind, what can I do ? I want to delete the ✓ icon.

[image]

Comment: Could you show us the relevant code. normally input elements do not have before pseudo elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding the style '!content-none' with the important modifier to the inputs className

Comment: But how I can give it to checked attribute ? 

checked:before:content-none like this ?

Comment: before:!content-none